# Using range lookup to return multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel, search-indexing

I am using the formula below to lookup the value in cell $A$286 against the values in range $B$2:$Q$284. If there are any matches, I want to return the corresponding values in column $A$2:$A$284 in a column format.  I am trying to look if a name in cell A286 matches names in range $B$2:$Q$284. If there is a match, I want to pick all the corresponding values in column A2:A284 (wherever there is a match) and return those values in a column format

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$284, SMALL(IF(($A$286=$B$2:$Q$284), ROW($B$2:$Q$284)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$Q$284))+1,""),COLUMN(A1)))
```

I checked multiple sources online and this formula seems to work (main source: get-digital-help.com/2011/06/22/vlookup-a-range-in-excel) but for me it's returning "#Value!"

Where could I be making an error and how should I rectify it? Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: I may be missing something, but I can't see VLOOKUP in this formula.

Comment: What I am trying to do is more complex than a v look up, instead of looking at just one column, I am trying to look at a range (multiple columns) and instead of returning just one corresponding value, I am aiming to return multiple corresponding values wherever there is a match

Comment: You mention the multiple values in the question, and someone familiar with using SMALL might figure out that you would replicate the formula to retrieve the multiple results.  But what you want to do isn't clear in the question, as you can tell from the number of times you've tried to re-explain it in comments.  This will get a more useful response if you add a visual to the question; an actual (minimal) example that shows some sample data and what the result should look like.

Comment: Also, it looks like you've tried to adapt a formula you found online.  It would be useful to cite one of the places you found it so people can see the original context.

Comment: I will add visuals tomorrow. In the meanwhile, this is the source that I used : https://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/06/22/vlookup-a-range-in-excel/

Comment: One thing to note: the formula you adapted is an array formula.  It must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter.

Answer (score 0):

The error is right in this part:

```
$A$286=$B$2:$Q$284
```

You can't compare a single cell to a range like that. Next time you want to troubleshoot an error like this, click on the cell with the error. Then click the little yellow flag that appears:

[image: #VALUE error with warning flag]

In that menu, choose "show calculation steps" to see where the error is coming from.

Normally, to do a lookup like this I would suggest something like:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$284,MATCH(A286,$B$2:$B$284,0))
```

But you might be trying to do something more complicated than that. It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks, how do I rectify this error?

Comment: There are many possible ways of removing the error, but it's not clear enough from your question what you are trying to do. I can make a guess.

Comment: I am trying to look if a name in cell A286 matches names in range $B$2:$Q$284. If there is a match, I want to pick all the corresponding values in column A2:A284 (wherever there is a match) and return those values in a column format